# Setting radio button default selected option in CSHTML Razor .NET

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a HTML markup like this:

```
<input type="radio" name="shipping" value="Worldwide"> All Locations<br>
<input type="radio" name="shipping" value="US" checked> US Only<br>
<input type="radio" name="shipping" value="GB"> UK Only


<input type="radio" name="type" value="all"> All Listings
<input type="radio" name="type" value="FixedPrice" checked> Fixed Price
<input type="radio" name="type" value="Auction"> Auction




   <input type="radio" name="condition" value="New" checked> Brand New<br>
                <input type="radio" name="condition" value="Used"> Used<br>
```

Basically what I'm trying to do here is save user preferences and then load them from my DB into these checkboxes like this:

```
 @if (ViewBag.UserPreferences!=null)
        {

        @:$("input[name='shipping'][value='" + @ViewBag.UserPreferences.ShippingLocation + "']").attr('checked', 'checked');
        @:$("input[name='type'][value='" + @ViewBag.UserPreferences.ListingType + "']").attr('checked', 'checked');
        @:$("input[name='condition'][value='" + @ViewBag.UserPreferences.Condition + "']").attr('checked', 'checked');


        }
```

Contents of `ViewBag.UserPreferences are exactly equal to the values that u see in value attribute of either of these tags up there.

What am I doing wrong here???

Comment: You should call this using **$(document).ready** event

Comment: @Fals it's in  document.ready already

Comment: Why in the world are you not using the `@Html.RadioButtonFor()` method to generate you radio buttons (which will correctly select the button based on the value of the property your binding to and give you validation etc with less code, with none of which you will get with your current code

Comment: @StephenMuecke very good point, I guess I'm just too much used to using regular html over .NET MVC's ones ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't need to escape from the single quotes to add the razor value.  Try this:

```
@:$("input[name='shipping'][value='@ViewBag.UserPreferences.ShippingLocation']").attr('checked', 'checked');
```

And I have also had luck with `<text>`:

```
<text>$("input[name='shipping'][value='@ViewBag.UserPreferences.ShippingLocation']").attr('checked', 'checked');</text>
```

Comment: Thanks ,works quite nicely, I can't believe I forgot ''!!